# If I want to cast integer types to floating point numbers, should I use float, CGFloat or double?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

It's probably not very consequential, but I want to make sure I'm doing this right.

Say I have a `long long` or an `int`, if I want to do `NSLog(@"%f", theirQuotient)`, should I cast each number a `float`, or a `CGFloat` or a `double`?

Comment: CGFloat is the same as double.

Comment: On 64 bit systems, not 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your choices are valid and which floating point type you use in general depends on your needs.

However in your particular example, passing the value as an argument to a variadic function (`NSLog`) then choose `double` - in (Objective-)C `float` values are promoted to `double` when passed as one of a variadic function additional parameters so you might as well pass a `double`.

To understand more look up arithmetic conversions and promotions in C - this is basic stuff you should understand if doing any arithmetic.

Comment: they are? If you declare a method parameter as CGFloat,and pass in a CGFloat, it gets promoted to double, passed in, and then "demoted" back to a float? Really?

Comment: `float` values are not promoted to `double` when passed as ordinary function parameters. `float` values are promoted to `double` specifically when they are passed through `...` arguments like `printf(const char *format, ...)`.

Comment: @DuncanC - Well spotted thanks, I'd missed the "variadic" part out.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes much more sense, since with variadic parameters, the compiler can't know the size like it can with declared parameters.